# Need an efficient strategy for removing compiler-imposed SAVE attribute for local variables

Tags: fortran

As part of a code modernization effort, I'm trying to eliminate saved state within functions and subroutines. The code in question fails unless it is built using a 'all variables SAVE' flag (such as `/SAVE` or `-save` under the Intel compiler).

I'm dealing with about 90,000 lines of code (over 500 functions & subroutines) and I'm faced with a few unattractive options:

#### The Extremely Tedious Conservative Approach

I can disable the compiler flag and globally add the `SAVE` directive to each routine's declaration header (skipping any routines that I've declared as `PURE` or `ELEMENTAL`), then iteratively remove it from routines, rebuilding and testing the code, and restoring it if testing fails. This is guaranteed to work but it seems like a massive and inelegant waste of time.

#### The Slightly Less Tedious Additive Approach

I can disable the compiler flag then iteratively add `SAVE` to suspicious routines, rebuilding and testing, and stopping once the code successfully runs. This is less tedious, but still fairly wasteful. Worse, it's not guaranteed to work if code testing hasn't covered every scenario where saved state is required.

#### The Question

Is there is a more efficient approach to detecting saved state within routines? Is this a job for a static analysis tool? Or am I doomed to the endless tedium of manual editing and testing?

(A natural question is *"Why bother?"* Three reasons: First, it's bad coding practice; state should be saved at the global, module, or object level, not within a specific routine. Second, pragmatically, local saved state interferes with code parallelization. Finally, minimizing compiler flags reduces the code's dependency on a particular compiler and removes hidden state from the build process.)

Comment: If you are not going to actually work on the code and don't need to port it to a compiler not supporting a `-save` option, what you want to do sounds bad, because it might introduce bugs that weren't there for functions that rely on saved variables. You will never catch all of those. The reasons you give for changing the code are insufficient to warrant introduction of (new) bugs.

Comment: If the code was in bug-fix-only mode, I might agree with you. The code is under active development and I see the problem of hidden state as serious enough to warrant eliminating. I'm comfortable with the risk of introducing/uncovering bugs during refactoring.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant, but in that case, can't the people that do the active development take care of it function by function as they change things?

Comment: If the code base has a future then you are going to have to head down this path at some stage.  I think static and dynamic correctness tools are important for this sort of task, regardless of your approach.

Comment: The code has two developers, and I'm one of them so there really isn't anyone to delegate this task to. :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you that what you're doing is the right thing to do (TM), but I don't have any solutions that would guarantee it's not going to be tedious. In any case, in order to get rid of a lot of saved state, not merely moving it from a compiler option into the code, might require more or less extensive refactoring of the code anyway.

Anyway, one thing worth trying is running your code under valgrind. Without such a global -save option, valgrind might catch some "use of uninitialized variable" errors.

Comment: Based on your advice, I'm pursuing the use of valgrind as a saved-state detector. One issue is that I'm not sure which 'uninitialized variable' messages are meaningful. The solution to that has been to build a toy 'saved state' program, compile it with -save and without, then run both through valgrind to see what messages pop up. Another approach I may take is comparing disassembled code and looking for patterns. Gruesome but possibly fruitful.